# Hover for an image

Tags: php, css

I want to create an image gallery and if the user hovers over an image it should be set to none and the text below it should be shown. But I have to set the image like this

```
echo "<div class=textimage style=background-image:url(pictures/head_censored.png)>Sample text</div>";
```

Like this, the picture it shown but the hover effect (background-image: none) is not applied. If i declare the image in the css file it works but as the pictures are always changing this is way too complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not your main problem, but you should use `"` around your attribute values, so make it `echo '<div class="textimage" style="bac...`

Comment: Thanks, but as you said this isn't the problem ;) You can't set parameter in css, can you? so I could use the url as paramter to define it in the css file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create something simple without making complicated javascript, a little css trick will do.

```
<div class='disappear'>
  <p class='text'>This image is about stuff 1</p>
  <img src='pictures/nicepeople.jpg' />
</div>
<div class='disappear'>
  <p class='text'>This image is about stuff 2</p>
  <img src='pictures/nicepeople.jpg' />
</div>
<div class='disappear'>
      <p class='text'>This image is about stuff 3</p>
      <img src='pictures/nicepeople.jpg' />
    </div>
<style type='text/css'>
 div.disappear p{
   display:none; 
 }
 div.disappear:hover p{
   display:block; 
 }
 div.disappear:hover img{
   display:none; 
 }
</style>
```

Wish you luck :)

Comment: Well, this was easy and clear to me, I have it now like this and it works like a charm ;)

Comment: `<div class='disappear' style=float:left>
  <p class='text'>This image is about stuff 1</p>
  <img src='pictures/head_blurred.png' />
</div>
<div class='disappear' style=float:left>
  <p class='text'>This image is about stuff 1</p>
  <img src='pictures/head_censored.png' />
</div>
<style type='text/css'>
 div.disappear p{
   display:none;
 }
 div.disappear:hover p{
   display:block;
 }
 div.disappear:hover img{
   visbility:hidden;
 }
</style>";`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work when you define the image inline because inline takes precedence over the external stylesheet. If you want to do it without javascript, instead of changing the background image, try changing the display property like so (in the css file):

```
.textimage:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

Then simply have the text in a separate div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually this can be accomplished quite easily with some javascript. I prefer jQuery for ease of use, but pick your own suitable flavor, it all boils down to javascript anyway.

So the trick here is to attach a javascript function to the "onhover" event of your image element.  So that your javascript function captures the event.

like so:

```
function changeImageTextLocation()
{
  document.getElementById(#imageID).innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById(#captionID).innerHTML = "Some other text";
}
```

Then using PHP attach that function to your element like so:

```
echo '<img onhover="changeImageTextLocation()" />';
```

When you load the page and hover over the element it should swap the text to the new location.  Note you may have to set the attribute "value" instead of innerHTML depending.  YMMV.

Let us know how it goes.

:)

Edit:  If you are trying to turn off the image, as in make it disappear in order to bring forward the "alt" text, then that is a matter of manipulating the CSS of your image element, which theoretically can also be accessed with javascript.  Cheers

Edit 2:  If you are trying to make the image go away so you can see alt text, then you could also try using javascript to unset the source "src" attribute for the element, and if you have "alt" defined that should do it.  There I think I got all possible interpretations of your question covered.

Comment: Well, javascript is new to me but I don't think this is the problem. Atm I got this
`require 'main.js';
echo '<img onhover="imagehover()" id=imageid src="pictures/head_blurred.png"/>';`

put this only prints out the function, it doesn't run it...pretty ugly and I don't understand why...

Comment: @Liam Schnell , I am 98% sure that you don't use "require" to bring a javascript file into your project. Javascript is a client side language, which means its executed on the end users browser rather than on the server.  "require" is specifically a PHP directive which is server side.  You have to embed the Javascript into a page using "<script></script>" tags.  Once you bring the script into the client side page your above code should execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the images dynamically, you can accomplish a hover with jQuery like this:

```
var storedBg = null;
$('.textimage').live({ 
  mouseenter: function() {
    // Clear the background image and update the text
    storedBg = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
    // update the text here
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    // restore the background image
    $(this).css('background-image', storedBg );
  }
});
```

This has the added benefit of working for future images loaded through AJAX calls.